# Visual Studio 2010 always thinks project is out of date, but nothing has changed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a very similar problem as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640339/vs2010-always-relinks-the-project).

I also upgraded a mixed solution of C++/CLI and C# projects from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2010. And now in Visual Studio 2010 one C++/CLI project always runs out of date.

Even if it has been compiled and linked just before and <kbd>F5</kbd> is hit, the messagebox "The project is out of date. Would you like to build it?" appears. This is very annoying because the DLL file is very low-tiered and forces almost all projects of the solution to rebuild.

My pdb settings are set to the default value ([suggested solution of this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640339/vs2010-always-relinks-the-project)).

Is it possible the get the reason why Visual Studio 2010 forces a rebuild or thinks a project is up to date?

Any other ideas why Visual Studio 2010 behaves like that?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547931/visual-studio-2015-program-out-of-date

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547931/visual-studio-2015-program-out-of-date

Answer (score 225, accepted):

*For Visual Studio/Express 2010 only. See other (easier) answers for VS2012, VS2013, etc*

To find [the missing file(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762930/vs2010-always-thinks-project-is-out-of-date-but-nothing-has-changed/2853912#2853912), use info from the article [Enable C++ project system logging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsproject/archive/2009/07/21/enable-c-project-system-logging.aspx) to enable debug logging in Visual Studio and let it *just tell you* what's causing the rebuild:

1. Open the `devenv.exe.config` file (found in `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\` or in `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\`). For Express versions the config file is named `V*Express.exe.config`.
2. Add the following after the `</configSections>` line:

   ```
   <system.diagnostics>
     <switches>
       <add name="CPS" value="4" />
     </switches>
   </system.diagnostics>
   ```
3. Restart Visual Studio
4. Open up [DbgView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647) and make sure it's capturing debug output
5. Try to debug (hit F5 in Visual Studio)
6. Search the debug log for any lines of the form:

   > devenv.exe Information: 0 : Project 'Bla\Bla\Dummy.vcxproj' not up to date because build input 'Bla\Bla\SomeFile.h' is missing.

   (I just hit Ctrl+F and searched for `not up to date`) These will be the references causing the project to be perpetually "out of date".

To correct this, either remove any references to the missing files from your project, or update the references to indicate their actual locations.

Note: If using 2012 or later then the snippet should be:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <switches>
   <add name="CPS" value="Verbose" />
  </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: > Open up DbgView and make sure it's capturing debug output.
How to make sure that capturing is started? I have the same problem with rebuild projects. But there is no any info in DebugView. I enabled first 5 option in menu 'Capture' of DebugView. (And thanks for good links in answer!)

Comment: Thank you Mosc for your excellent answer.

Preforming the steps recommended by you allowed me to find what was the specific problem in my case (adding project optimizations).

Your method allowed me to find the exact error message. From there googling it and finding this relevant post:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=77238

was super easy! Your solution is great as it fits many problems.

Thanks!!!

Comment: This helped us figure it out; however, we also had to delete our intermediate build directory before the last of the .H references went away -- probably to refresh the StdAfx.obj? Anyway, after deleting all the intermediate build folders and cleaning up the project files, we're also good to go.

Comment: Thank you - now why isn't that in the regular output window?

Comment: If you are using VS2012, there is a slightly different snippet to paste in to the config file.  This is linked from the original article, but just in case:[Enable C++ and Javascript project system tracing VS2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andrewarnottms/archive/2012/06/07/enable-c-and-javascript-project-system-tracing.aspx)

Comment: The article says `Why the name “CPS” for our trace switch?  Just an implementation detail for this release.` - is there a particular name to be used with Visual Studio **2005**?

Comment: I can confirm this approach also works with VC++ Express 2010. It might be useful to know that if you are using VC++ Express, you should be looking for the VCExpress.exe.config file, not the devenv.exe.config file. That took me a while to figure out.

Comment: This answer is made of pure win and just oozing with awesomeness. This should be in every engineer's toolbox anytime VS seems to flake out and build what you think is up-to-date for no apparent reason at all. Thank you *very* much.

Comment: I used this approach with VS2012 (as suggested here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andrewarnottms/archive/2012/06/07/enable-c-and-javascript-project-system-tracing.aspx). With VS2012 the output can be directed to a file, no need for DbgView. However now I can't turn it off (!!!). I reverted the `devenv.exe.config` to its original state, but VS2012 continues to generate this debug output. Does anyone know how to turn it off?

Comment: Warning: I edited devenv.exe.config and now Visual Studio 2010 does not start. I reedited the file back to the way it was and it still will not start. This is on Windows 7 x64 Professional.

Comment: Great! I found a cpp file last modified date is future! I think I reverted or modified it when I was testing something with date change. I could find that cpp file in 5 minutes. Thank you ; )

Comment: weird. i dont have denv.exe.config file in that path. i'm using visual studio 2012 express for windows phone on windows 8 machine

Comment: FYI, this doesn't appear to work anymore in VS2013 - after editing the config file, it doesn't generate anything of interest in DebugView.

Comment: Sometimes the problem can fixed simply by manually deleting all intermediate and output files. Remove all Debug, Release etc. folders.

Comment: FYI, files, that are not important or considered at build time (e.g. not used header-files, readme.txt,...), will not be found through that method.

Comment: For VS2012/VS2013 and on you better take other approaches; just set MSBuild project build output verbosity to Diagnostic, and check the output for 'not up to date'.

Answer (score 166):

In Visual Studio 2012 I was able to achieve the same result easier than in the accepted solution.

I changed the option in menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Projects and Solutions* → *Build and Run* → *MSBuild project build output verbosity" from *Minimal* to *Diagnostic*.

Then in the build output I found the same lines by searching for "not up to date":

> Project 'blabla' is not up to date. Project item 'c:\foo\bar.xml' has 'Copy to Output Directory' attribute set to 'Copy always'.

Comment: This also works in VS2013, where the config file tweak doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: This worked very well for me. Turned out I had a circular reference (project1 -> project2, project2 -> project1.dll), which caused most of the solution to build each time. It wasn't even in use.

Comment: With C#, I could not find anything with "not up to date", the magic word seems to be "is newer than"

Comment: `1>Project not up to date because build input 'C:\...\ReadMe.txt' is missing.` :O !!?!

Comment: Fantastic, even with full logging the decision to build the project is first so you won't have to search through thousands of log entries to find the solution using this method :-) Was the same for me, copy to output directory set to always instead of if newer.

Comment: This worked. In my case, the problem was that some files that were removed in source control were still included in the project in Solution Explorer.

Comment: In VS2013 you may also have to search for `was modified at` in diagnostics mode because I had no `not up to date` outputs.

Comment: Still not sure how to solve a "Up-to-date check called on non-active configuration."

Comment: In Visual Studio 2015 for C++: 1>myfile.cxx will be compiled as FILETHATWASMODIFIED.H was modified at 7/10/2017 8:44:23 AM. (TaskId:29)

Comment: For me it was `Output file "<path to file>" does not exist.` with path to output of custom build step in VS 2015.

Answer (score 60):

This happened to me today. I was able to track down the cause: The project included a header file which no longer existed on disk.

Removing the file from the project solved the problem.

Comment: No, I do not have any header files that are not existant on the disk.
But how were you able to track down the cause? How did you find out that there was a missing file?
Perhaps I can find out something more about my problem by checking in the same way like you.

Comment: There was a different solution when this happened to me.  Probably pretty obscure, but I was compiling the project from one computer, then another, and discovered I'd accidentally set the time to AM on one computer and PM on the other.  The drastic time difference caused one of the computers to either always compile everything, or never to compile anything even when I modified source files.

Comment: This worked for me in spite of the header file existing.  Using the answer below to enable logging, it thought a header file was missing.  I removed its dependency, added it back in, and minimal rebuild worked again!

Comment: clock skew will cause most build systems to implode

Answer (score 15):

We also ran into this issue and found out how to resolve it.

The issue was as stated above "The file no longer exists on the disk."

This is not quite correct. The file does exist on the disk, but the .VCPROJ file is referencing the file somewhere else.

You can 'discover' this by going to the "include file view" and clicking on each include file in turn until you find the one that Visual Studio can not find. You then ADD that file (as an existing item) and delete the reference that can not be found and everything is OK.

A valid question is: How can Visual Studio even build if it does not know where the include files are?

We think the .vcproj file has some relative path to the offending file somewhere that it does not show in the Visual Studio GUI, and this accounts for why the project will actually build even though the tree-view of the includes is incorrect.

Comment: The reason VC can build is because they're header files -- and header files don't actually get compiled. If any of the header files are actually used by a .C/.CPP file, then and only then will the build fail. So the dependency checker (which looks for the header file) marks the project as needing a rebuild, but the actual compiler (which just ignores the list of header files) can succeed.

Comment: Unbelievably... this also happens if you have a stale reference to a *text* file (that is NOT even part of the build anyway even if it did exist!!) in your .vcxproj file. I had generated a project with the wizard, and it included a ReadMe.txt file, which I deleted off the disk, but forgot to remove from the vcxproj.

Comment: I can't find any file that I can't open (except one, but that is on the hard drive. It says something like that kind of file can't be opened on the Visual Studio 2010 Express SKU or something like that.

Comment: What is the "include file view" and how do you get to it?

Comment: *Include File View* is perhaps the Include Files section in the Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer helped me on the right path to figuring out how to solve this problem for the screwed up project I had to start working with. However, I had to deal with a very large number of bad include headers. With the verbose debug output, removing one caused the IDE to freeze for 30 seconds while outputting debug spew, which made the process go very slowly.

I got impatient and wrote a quick-and-dirty Python script to check the (Visual Studio 2010) project files for me and output all the missing files at once, along with the filters they're located in. You can find it as a Gist here: https://gist.github.com/antiuniverse/3825678 (or this [fork that supports relative paths](https://gist.github.com/ixe013/ad718a7ea1a2a158c4a4))

Example:

```
D:\...> check_inc.py sdk/src/game/client/swarm_sdk_client.vcxproj
[Header Files]:
  fx_cs_blood.h   (cstrike\fx_cs_blood.h)
  hud_radar.h   (cstrike\hud_radar.h)
[Game Shared Header Files]:
  basecsgrenade_projectile.h   (..\shared\cstrike\basecsgrenade_projectile.h)
  fx_cs_shared.h   (..\shared\cstrike\fx_cs_shared.h)
  weapon_flashbang.h   (..\shared\cstrike\weapon_flashbang.h)
  weapon_hegrenade.h   (..\shared\cstrike\weapon_hegrenade.h)
  weapon_ifmsteadycam.h   (..\shared\weapon_ifmsteadycam.h)
[Source Files\Swarm\GameUI - Embedded\Base GameUI\Headers]:
  basepaenl.h   (swarm\gameui\basepaenl.h)
  ...
```

Source code:

```py
#!/c/Python32/python.exe
import sys
import os
import os.path
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

ns = '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003}'

#Works with relative path also
projectFileName = sys.argv[1]

if not os.path.isabs(projectFileName):
   projectFileName = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), projectFileName)

filterTree = ET.parse(projectFileName+".filters")
filterRoot = filterTree.getroot()
filterDict = dict()
missingDict = dict()

for inc in filterRoot.iter(ns+'ClInclude'):
    incFileRel = inc.get('Include')
    incFilter = inc.find(ns+'Filter')
    if incFileRel != None and incFilter != None:
        filterDict[incFileRel] = incFilter.text
        if incFilter.text not in missingDict:
            missingDict[incFilter.text] = []

projTree = ET.parse(projectFileName)
projRoot = projTree.getroot()

for inc in projRoot.iter(ns+'ClInclude'):
    incFileRel = inc.get('Include')
    if incFileRel != None:
        incFile = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(projectFileName), incFileRel))
        if not os.path.exists(incFile):
            missingDict[filterDict[incFileRel]].append(incFileRel)

for (missingGroup, missingList) in missingDict.items():
    if len(missingList) > 0:
        print("["+missingGroup+"]:")
        for missing in missingList:
            print("  " + os.path.basename(missing) + "   (" + missing + ")")
```

Comment: Modified your code to support relative paths. Feel free to update your gist and remove the link to my fork!

Comment: This worked great for me!  What a time saver!  Thanks!  I had NOTHING in the diagnostic output that told me what was wrong but your utility showed me!

Comment: Another fork to enum a dir and call it on each found vcxproj https://gist.github.com/paulsapps/4992d2d460f4ef44538d62c9e875ca78

Answer (score 8):

I've deleted a cpp and some header files from the solution (and from the disk) but still had the problem.

Thing is, every file the compiler uses goes in a *.tlog file in your temp directory. 
When you remove a file, this *.tlog file is not updated. That's the file used by incremental builds to check if your project is up to date.

Either edit this .tlog file manually or clean your project and rebuild.

Comment: This was it for me!  I spent hours after fixing the missing include files, STILL was out of date, logging showed inconclusive grabage for what was missing.  Needed to get rid of those TLOG files!  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem, but in my case there were no files missing, there was an error in how the pdb output file was defined: I forgot the suffix .pdb (I found out with the debug logging trick).

To solve the problem I changed, in the vxproj file, the following line:

```
<ProgramDataBaseFileName>MyName</ProgramDataBaseFileName>
```

to

```
<ProgramDataBaseFileName>MyName.pdb</ProgramDataBaseFileName>
```

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem in VS2013 (Update 5) and there can be two reasons for that, both of which you can find by enabling "Detailed" build output under "Tools"->"Projects and Solutions"->"Build and Run".

1. `"Forcing recompile of all source files due to missing PDB "..."`
   This happens when you disable debug information output in your compiler options (Under Project settings: „C/C++“->“Debug Information Format“ to „None“ and „Linker“->“Generate Debug Info“ to „No“: ). If you have left „C/C++“->“Program Database File Name“ at the default (which is „$(IntDir)vc$(PlatformToolsetVersion).pdb“), VS will not find the file due to a bug (https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/833494/project-with-debug-information-disabled-always-rebuilds).
   To fix it, simply clear the file name to "" (empty field).
2. `"Forcing rebuild of all source files due to a change in the command line since the last build."`
   This seems to be a known VS bug too (https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/833943/forcing-rebuild-of-all-source-files-due-to-a-change-in-the-command-line-since-the-last-build) and seems to be fixed in newer versions (but not VS2013). I known of no workaround, but if you do, by all means, post it here.

Comment: This why my issue. None of the "not up to date" messages where on mine and it took forever for us to track this down. 

Also removing it or setting it to $(IntDir)$(ProjectName).pdb worked for us (be sure to change it for both debug and release configurations)

Answer (score 4):

Another simple solution referenced by [Visual Studio Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/873b7728-9eb6-4e4f-bcad-ccc128bc2bbb).

Changing configuration: menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Projects and Solutions* → *VC++ Project Settings* → *Solution Explorer Mode* to *Show all files*.

Then you can see all files in Solution Explorer.

Find the files marked by the yellow icon and remove them from the project.

It's OK.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if anyone else has this same problem, but my project's properties had `"Configuration Properties" -> C/C++ -> "Debug Information Format"` set to "None", and when I switched it back to the default "Program Database (/Zi)", that stopped the project from recompiling every time.

Comment: +1 this works for me as well, on Visual Studio 2013. Specifically, when I switch it *back* to None, it works fine again as well.

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio 2013 -- "Forcing recompile of all source files due to missing PDB". I turned on detailed build output to locate the issue: I enabled "Detailed" build output under "Tools" → "Projects and Solutions" → "Build and Run".

I had several projects, all C++, I set the option for under project settings: (C/C++ → Debug Information Format) to Program Database (/Zi) for the problem project. However, this did not stop the problem for that project. The problem came from one of the other C++ projects in the solution.

I set *all* C++ projects to "Program Database (/Zi)". This fixed the problem.

Again, the project reporting the problem was not the problem project. Try setting all projects to "Program Database (/Zi)" to fix the problem.

Comment: VS2015 is the same regarding the setting for verbose build output

Answer (score 3):

I met this problem today, however it was a bit different. I had a CUDA DLL project in my solution. Compiling in a clean solution was OK, but otherwise it failed and the compiler always treated the CUDA DLL project as not up to date.

I tried the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5754740/1341371).

But there is no missing header file in my solution. Then I found out the reason in my case.

I have changed the project's Intermediate Directory before, although it didn't cause trouble. *And now when I changed the CUDA DLL Project's Intermediate Directory back to $(Configuration)\, everything works right again.*

I guess there is some minor problem between CUDA Build Customization and non-default Intermediate Directory.

Comment: Using VS2013 (C#), I've experimented with setting IntermediateOutputPath.  If this points to a folder on a different drive then the solution, incremental building stops working - MSBuild complains that some source file is always out of date with some intermediate file (usually a PDB).  See [my blog post](http://ugumba.wordpress.com/2014/03/19/visual-studio-insists-projects-are-out-of-date-when-intermediateoutputpath-is-on-different-drive/).

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem and followed the above instructions (the accepted answer) to locate the missing files, but not without scratching my head. Here is my summary of what I did. To be accurate these are not missing files since they are not required by the project to build (at least in my case), but they are references to files that don't exist on disk which are not really required.

Here is my story:

1. Under Windows 7 the file is located at `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\%`. There are two similar files `devenv.exe.config.config` and `devenv.exe.config`. You want to change later one.
2. Under Windows 7, you don't have permission to edit this file being in program files. Just copy it somewhere else (desktop) change it and than copy it back to the program files location.
3. I was trying to figure out how to connect [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) to the IDE to see the missing files. Well, you don't have to do anything. Just run it, and it will capture all the messages. Make sure `Capture Events` menu option is selected in `Capture` menu which by default should be selected.
4. DebugView will NOT display all the missing files at once (at least it didn't for me)! You would have DebugView running and than run the project in Visual Studio 2010. It will prompt the `project out of date` message, select *Yes* to build and DebugView will show the *first* file that is missing or causing the rebuild. Open the project file (not solution file) in Notepad and search for that file and delete it. You are better off closing your project and reopening it again while doing this delete. Repeat this process until DebugView no longer shows any files missing.
5. It's kind of helpful to set the message filter to *not up to date* from the DebugView toolbar button or *Edit* → *Filter/Highlight* option. That way the only messages it displays are the one that has `not up to date' string in it.

I had lots of files that were unnecessary references and removing them all fixed the issue following the above steps.

**Second way to find all the missing files at once**

There is a second way to find these files all at once, but it involves (a) source control and (b) integration of it with Visual Studio 2010. *Using Visual Studio 2010*, add your project to a desired location or dummy location in source control. It will try to add all the files, including those that don't exist on disk as well but referenced in the project file. Go to your source control software like [Perforce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perforce), and it should mark these files which don't exist on disk in a different color scheme. Perforce shows them with a black lock on them. These are your missing references. Now you have a list of them all, and you can delete all of them from your project file using Notepad and your project would not complain about being *out of date*.

Answer (score 2):

For me it was the presence of a non-existing  header file on "Header Files" inside the project. After removing this entry (right-click > Exclude from Project) first time recompiled, then directly

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 5 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

and no attempt of rebuilding without modification was done. I think is a check-before-build implemented by VS2010 (not sure if documented, could be) which triggers the "AlwaysCreate" flag.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the command-line MSBuild command (not the Visual Studio IDE), for example if you are targetting AppVeyor or you just prefer the command line, you can add this option to your MSBuild command line:

```
/fileLoggerParameters:LogFile=MyLog.log;Append;Verbosity=diagnostic;Encoding=UTF-8
```

As documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx#) (warning: usual MSDN verbosity). When the build finishes, search for the string `will be compiled` in the log file created during the build, `MyLog.log`.

Comment: /verbosity:detailed will also give the same information but is not as verbose. You can then search for "will be compiled as".

Comment: You should also search for "Source compilation required" which will also find links

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Professional with Update 4 but didn't find resolution with any of the other suggestions, however, I did manage to resolve the issue for my Team project.

Here's what I did to cause the problem -

- Created a new class object (Project -> Add Class)
- Renamed the file via Solution Explorer and clicked yes when asked if I wanted to automatically rename all references to match

Here's what I did to solve the problem -

- Go to Team Explorer Home
- Click Source Control Explorer
- Drill into the folder where all of the class/project files are
- Found the ORIGINAL filename in the list and deleted it via right-click
- Build

If this is the case for you then just be extra sure that you're deleting the phantom file rather than the actual one you want to keep in the project.

Answer (score 1):

Most build systems use data time stamps to determine when rebuilds should happen - the date/time stamp of any output files is checked against the last modified time of the dependencies - if any of the dependencies are fresher, then the target is rebuilt.

This can cause problems if any of the dependencies somehow get an invalid data time stamp as it's difficult for the time stamp of any build output to ever exceed the timestamp of a file supposedly created in the future :P

Comment: Is it possible the get the reason why VS2010 forces a rebuild or thinks a project is uptodate?

Comment: In VS6 or perhaps VS2005 there was a weird little property dialog one would get when right clicking on a project that had tabs showing the dependencies, and outputs, of each file in a project. I don't know how to get the equivalent report in VS2008 (or VS2010)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and found this:

http://curlybrace.blogspot.com/2005/11/visual-c-project-continually-out-of.html

> Visual C++ Project continually out-of-date (`winwlm.h macwin32.h rpcerr.h macname1.h` missing)
>
> #### Problem:
>
> In Visual C++ .Net 2003, one of my projects always claimed to be out of date, even though nothing had changed and no errors had been reported in the last build.
>
> Opening the BuildLog.htm file for the corresponding project showed a list of PRJ0041 errors for these files, none of which appear on my system anywhere:
>   winwlm.h macwin32.h rpcerr.h macname1.h
>
> Each error looks something like this:
>
> ```
>   MyApplication : warning PRJ0041 : Cannot find missing dependency 'macwin32.h' for file 'MyApplication.rc'.
> ```
>
> Your project may still build, but may continue to appear out of date until this file is found.
>
> #### Solution:
>
> Include `afxres.h` instead of `resource.h` inside the project's .rc file.
>
> The project's .rc file contained "#include resource.h". Since the resource compiler does not honor preprocessor `#ifdef` blocks, it will tear through and try to find include files it should be ignoring. Windows.h contains many such blocks. Including afxres.h instead fixed the PRJ0041 warnings and eliminated the "Project is out-of-date" error dialog.

Answer (score 1):

In my case one of the projects contains multiple IDL files. The MIDL compiler generates a DLL data file called 'dlldata.c' for each of them, regardless of the IDL file name. This caused Visual Studio to compile the IDL files on every build, even without changes to any of the IDL files.

The workaround is to configure a unique output file for each IDL file (the MIDL compiler always generates such a file, even if the /dlldata switch is omitted):

- Right-click the IDL file
- Select *Properties - MIDL - Output*
- Enter a unique file name for the *DllData File* property

Answer (score 1):

I spent many hours spent tearing out my hair over this. The build output wasn't consistent; different projects would be "not up to date" for different reasons from one build to the next consecutive build.
I eventually found that the culprit was **DropBox** (3.0.4). I junction my source folder from ...\DropBox into my projects folder (not sure if this is the reason), but DropBox somehow "touches" files *during* a build. Paused syncing and everything is consistently up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few potential reasons and - as noted - you need to first diagnose them by setting MSBuild verbosity to 'Diagnostic'. Most of the time the stated reason would be self explanatory and you'd be able to act on it immediatelly, BUT occasionally MSBuild would erroneously claim that some files are modified and need to be copied.

If that is the case, you'd need to either disable NTFS tunneling or duplicate your output folder to a new location.  [Here it is in more words.](http://ofekshilon.com/2015/08/16/visual-studio-projects-that-just-keep-rebuilding-or-how-quantum-mechanics-mess-up-your-build/)

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me multiple times and then went away, before I could figure out why. In my case it was:

**Wrong system time in the dual boot setup!**

Turns out, my dual boot with Ubuntu was the root cause!! I've been too lazy to fix up Ubuntu to stop messing with my hardware clock. When I log into Ubuntu, the time jumps 5 hours forward.

Out of bad luck, I built the project once, with the wrong system time, then corrected the time. As a result, all the build files had wrong timestamps, and VS would think they are all out of date and would rebuild the project.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem arose in a WPF project where some files had their 'Build Action' property set to 'Resource' and their 'Copy to Output Directory' set to 'Copy if newer'. The solution seemed to be to change the 'Copy to Output Directory' property to 'Do not copy'.

msbuild knows not to copy 'Resource' files to the output - but still triggers a build if they're not there. Maybe that could be considered a bug?

It's hugely helpful with the answers here hinting how to get msbuild to spill the beans on why it keeps building everything!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Visual Studio 2005, and my solution consisted of five projects in the following dependency (first built at top):

```
Video_Codec depends on nothing
Generic_Graphics depends on Video_Codec
SpecificAPI_Graphics depends on Generic_Graphics
Engine depends on Specific_Graphics
Application depends on Engine.
```

I was finding that the Video_Codec project wanted a full build even after a full clean then rebuild of the solution.

I fixed this by ensuring the `pdb` output file of both the C/C++ and linker matched the location used by the other working projects. I also switched RTTI on.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the Debugging Command arguments for the project, this will also trigger the project needs to be rebuilt message. Even though the target itself is not affected by the Debugging arguments, the project properties have changed. If you do rebuild though, the message should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Another one on Visual Studio 2015 SP3, but I have encountered a similar issue on Visual Studio 2013 a few years back.

My issue was that somehow a wrong cpp file was used for precompiled headers (so I had two cpp files that created the precompiled headers). Now why did Visual Studio change the flags on the wrong cpp to 'create precompiled headers' without my request I have no clue, but it did happen... maybe some plugin or something???

Anyway, the wrong cpp file includes the version.h file which is changed on every build. So Visual Studio rebuilds all headers and because of that the whole project.

Well, now it's back to normal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I had a VC++ project that was always compiling all files and had been previously upgraded from VS2005 to VS2010 (by other people). I found that all cpp files in the project except StdAfx.cpp were set to Create (/Yc) the precompiled header.  I changed this so that only StdAfx.cpp was set to create the precompiled header and the rest were set to Use (/Yu) the precompiled header and this fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Visual Studio 2013 and just updated to the Windows 10 May 2019 update and compiling suddenly had to be redone every time, regardless of changes. Tried renaming the pch to ProjectName instead of TargetName, looked for missing files with the detailed log and that Python script, but in the end it was my time was not synced with MS's servers (by like milliseconds).

What resolved this for me was

- "Adjust date and time" in the control panel
- "Sync Now"

Now my projects don't need to be recompiled for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you placed some newline or other whitespace. Remove it and press F5 again.

Answer (score -3):

The .NET projects are always recompiled regardless. Part of this is to keep the IDE up to date (such as IntelliSense). I remember asking this question on an Microsoft forum years ago, and this was the answer I was given.

Comment: In VS2008 the project did not rebuild everytime. This is very annoying because the dll is very low-tiered and forces almost all of my dlls to rebuild.

Something went wrong on migration and I cannot figure out what.

Comment: 2008, 2010, 2012 and 2013 do no rebuilt .NET projects everytime

Comment: There is back ground compilation going on (and remember this answer is 10 years old) to keep the intellisense functional. I