# How can I get a list on criterias why Visual Studio does a compilation?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I have [the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762930) that C++ compiler does a recompile without any changes done.

Does anyone of you know how to get a list on criterias why VisualStudio decides to start a compilation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VS2010 always thinks project is out of date but nothing has changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762930/vs2010-always-thinks-project-is-out-of-date-but-nothing-has-changed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question has been handeled and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762930/vs2010-always-thinks-project-is-out-of-date-but-nothing-has-changed).

Answer (score 0):

Look up MSBuild

Comment: Where exactly can I find the reasons in MSBuild?