# what microsoft visual studio 2010 build message mean?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, build

I have created a c++ 'win32 console application' project named 'a' using mvs2010. When I build the project the following message is displayed in 'build' output window,

```
Creating "Debug\a.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
```

what does it mean ? is it any kind of error i should taken care of ?
thanks in advance...

Comment: This post might be relevant:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054066/vs2010-project-is-not-up-to-date-because-alwayscreate-was-specified?

Comment: Do you mean it's displayed every time, even when you build after not changing anything? If so, the links soon and taocp posted are relevant. If not, don't worry; that's just part of the way MSBuild prepares for a build and is nothing to do with your code. It's a file MSBuild uses to track whether builds were successful or not, and should be deleted at the end of the build (if successful).

Comment: You've just got the "chatty" mode turn on for MSBuild.  So it tells you what it is doing.  If you don't want to see it or they confuse you too much then turn the verbosity mode back to Quiet.  Tools + Options, Projects and Solutions, Build and Run.