# Why does Visual Studio think I need to build a project?

Tags: visual-studio

One of the projects in my Visual Studio Solution constantly thinks it needs to be rebuilt.  How can I tell why this is the case?  I prefer to be able to do this without having to use a command line, but will do so if I must.  A long time ago, I used a debug mode in gnu's make to get this sort of information.  I was sure I had made notes about doing this with some sort of output logger and with changing a setting somewhere, but I cannot find the notes, and may simply be miss-remembering.

Comment: Do you have "phantom" files (files that are not referenced) in your visual studio solution ?  for example, a unreferenced header file entry in the solution, but the file is not on disk ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this has already been answered, see:
[Visual Studio: project is not up to date "because "AlwaysCreate" was specified"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054066/vs2010-project-is-not-up-to-date-because-alwayscreate-was-specified)
And see the answer about setting "CPS" to log this kind of info, and then using DebugView to see it.