# How to solve the infamouns AlwaysCreate=True rebuild issue with msbuild?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, build-process, visual-studio-2012

I've spent far too much time trying to solve the problem of msbuild rebuilding your projects without any special reasons.

As a remark, I did these on Visual Studio 2012, but probably most of these would also happen with 2010.

I will provide all the steps found so far and wait for the real solution, as crearly what I found so far online did not solve the problem.

1. Enable detailed build logs inside `devenv.exe.config` so we can debug what really happens. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8084718/99834). I assume that's the same as changing it from `Tools->Project and Solutions->Build and Run->MSBuild Project build output->verbosity`.
2. Assured that IntDir runs on the same disk as TargetDir (details)[http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/760370/linker-does-not-link-if-intermediate-directory-with-changed-object-files-is-on-another-drive]
3. looking for files added to the project that are missing form disk, that's almost impossible, should I use the mechanicalturk for this?
4. Tried to look use `findstr /si AlwaysCreate` but without any outcomes.

Things that could have an impact:

- I am building on a network drive which is mapped by Parallels, so I can use the same files under OS X and Windows.

Additional debug information:

- [build.log](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8004159/temp/build.log)

Comment: You are seriously on the wrong track, that string just appears in the build log to indicate that the .unsuccessfulbuild file should always be created.  Which is how MSBuild can tell that the build failed for undiagnosable reasons, that file survives.  You see it getting deleted again at the end of the build.  Digging through all that build spew is otherwise cruel and unusual punishment to inflict on an SO user.

Comment: You could rule out the network drive by trying the build/rebuild with a local copy instead.

Comment: I have news, no diference between network and local build but I discovered that build works well from GUI, but when I run "msbuild" from the command line it will rebuild most of the stuff, the GUI does not.

Comment: Clearly there is a big difference between doing "build" on the solution in the GUI or doing `msbuild solution.sln /p:Cofiguration=release /t:build` - I folowed http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms164311.aspx -- still something is fishy around.

Comment: a startpoint to see what VS is doing is setting the MSBuildEmitSolution environment variable to "1", then you get the result of VS converting the solution to the msbuild script it actually runs (extension of the file is .metaproj, same dir as solution)

Comment: One alternative is to call devstudio to build instead of using msbuild, probably this would work as expected but still this smells like another bug in dev studio.

Comment: I am hunting the same issue. Did you have any progress in this?

Comment: @fschmitt Sorry, escaped the m$ world long time ago I doubt I want to go back there. i have enough fun dealing with Linux and MacOS :)