# Post-build event always runs in MSBUILD VS2013

Tags: visual-c++, msbuild, visual-studio-2013

This is very [similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185638/solving-the-visual-studio-2010-alwayscreate-rebuild-issue), except for the problem except the problem exists on MSBUILD after I fix it for VS2013.  The post-build event is running even though the compiler and linker think the project is up-to-date.

Any thoughts on how to prevent the post-build event from running here?

```
1>Project "D:\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).

1>InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating ".\..\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX.39DEE505.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.\

ClCompile:
  All outputs are up-to-date.
  All outputs are up-to-date.
ResourceCompile:
  All outputs are up-to-date.
Link:
  All outputs are up-to-date.
  WpnSiteOverlayManager.vcxproj -> D:\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\..\bin\Release\XXX.dll
PostBuildEvent:
  "..\..\..\Components\DevTools\Build\BuildCommand.exe" /p "..\..\..\Products" "D:\XXX
  ....
  buildcommand completed successfully
FinalizeBuildStatus:
  Deleting file ".\..\intermediate\release\XXX\XXX.39DEE505.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
  Touching ".\..\intermediate\release\XXX\XXX.39DEE505.tlog\XXX.lastbuildstate".
1>Done Building Project "D:\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX.vcxproj" (default targets).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This functionality is built-in in MsBuild for .Net projects (search for PostBuildEvent in Microsoft.Common.Targets, also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972820/run-an-msbuild-target-only-if-project-is-actually-built/13974783#13974783)), here is a simplified version. The principle is you get a timestamp of your output file(s) before the build, and another one after the build, then compare them. If they are the same, obviously nothing was really built. There's a miriad of possible insertion points for this logic, here I just picked the link stage which should do just fine:

```
<Target Name="GetTimeStampBeforeLink" BeforeTargets="Link">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectOutputFiles Include="$(TargetPath)" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputTimeStampBeforeLink>%(ProjectOutputFiles.ModifiedTime)</OutputTimeStampBeforeLink>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Target>

<Target Name="GetTimeStampAfterLink" AfterTargets="Link">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputTimeStampAfterLink>%(ProjectOutputFiles.ModifiedTime)</OutputTimeStampAfterLink>
    <OutputFilesModified Condition="'$(OutputTimeStampBeforeLink)' != '$(OutputTimeStampAfterLink)'">True</OutputFilesModified>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```

You can insert this code right into your projectfile, but a better idea is to save it in a seperate file so you can reuse if for other projects by importing it wherever you want it. Also you can add files to check by adding to the `ProjectOutputFiles` ItemGroup.

Now all is left is disabling the PostBuildEvent. MsBuild already has a mechanism for that since postbuild event invokation is conditional on a propery named `PostBuildEventUseInBuild`, so we set this to false if output files are not modified:

```
<Target Name="DisablePostBuildEvent" AfterTargets="GetTimeStampAfterLink">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEventUseInBuild Condition='"$(OutputFilesModified)' != 'True'">false</PostBuildEventUseInBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```

Answer (score 5):

A slightly simpler variation on stjin's answer:

```
<Target Name="DisablePostBuildEvent" AfterTargets="Link" BeforeTargets="PostBuildEvent">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEventUseInBuild Condition="'$(LinkSkippedExecution)' == 'True'">false</PostBuildEventUseInBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```

This only executes the post build event if the linker actually executed.