# VS2010SP1: Project always out of date when debugging

Tags: c++, debugging, project, visual-studio-2010

I experienced this problem in VS2010 before, and solved it looking at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762930/vs2010-always-thinks-project-is-out-of-date-but-nothing-has-changed). However, now that I upgraded my VS to SP1, it appeared again. I tried to solve it the same way, enabling C++ projects logging and using [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647). But I can't get to see any output in DebugView, no matter what I do. I also tried raising the Build output verbosity (Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build And Run), but couldn't find any clue.

As in the original problem, the projects reported as out of date are always unmanaged C++ projects. The solution has C#, VB.NET, C++/CLI and C++ projects. What I'm trying to run is a VB.NET exe which uses some C++ projects through C++/CLI wrappers.

Any hint on how to troubleshoot this?

**UPDATE**: Solved it with a clean checkout. However, it's a shame that there is no longer a way to troubleshoot this kind of errors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible you were testing with the date in the future and saved a source file in the future? While clean/rebuild all should fix this, VS seems to go batty and stay there until I resave the file in the present.

Another last-ditch thing that sometimes solves these problems that works 'like a reboot' if you have just the source-code in version control: Check everything in, close VS and anything using files in your project, move all your project folders to a backup folder, and do a force-get latest version of each. Sometimes 'clean project' doesn't cut it.

If that doesn't work and you can't find a missing .h ... You can always fire up Process Monitor, set a filter, and dig in there.

Admittely all just stabs in the dark. Hope one hits the burgler! ;-)

Comment: I didn't touch my date settings, so gonna try a clean checkout

Comment: Not sure why it sometimes takes this to solve the problem. Only thought of it here because a co-worker did it and fixed things (different problem, forget what) after days of headbanging and and even having her VS reinstalled didn't fix it!

Comment: Definitely added this to my "try-this-if-all-fails" list :P

Answer (score 0):

After a compiler upgrade you should do a rebuild-all, if you haven't done that already.

For native C++ projects you can get "project out of date", but still nothing to build, if you have some include files in your project that doesn't actually exits. Like if you have deleted some unused .h files, but they are still part of the project.

Comment: Yep, tried cleaning and building the whole solution. No cigar. About the missing file, I think that is the source of the problem, but I double checked the offending projects and all references from Solution Explorer point to existing files. About checking the rest, our solution is too big...