# VC++ Winforms auto generated project won't debug VS2010: "This Project is out of Date"

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, compiler-errors

On `VS 2010 C++ Express` I am getting an error and my solution won't compile.

**Here's what happens:**

1. I open Visual Studio. (Obviously)
2. I click on "New Project" on the "Welcome" page.
3. I select "Windows Forms Application," name it, and click "OK."
4. I click on the debug button.
5. It says "The project is out of date."

**I don't do anything else.** No saving, no waiting. I wrote down what I did exactly when I did it. I've repeated this many times, and it still won't work.

**Am I forgetting to add another file to my solution to help it compile?** I didn't change the time, like others have said might affect it. It is on my harddrive, so it's a fresh project.

---

**Other Questions that Haven't Helped Me:**

- **[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359278/vs2010sp1-project-always-out-of-date-when-debugging):** Nothing in it applied to me.
- **[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762930/vs2010-always-thinks-project-is-out-of-date-but-nothing-has-changed):** All answers said a file was missing, but how could that be when it was just autogenerated two minutes ago? BTW: This is my first solution since I installed a week or so ago; I've just been repeating this process a few times. The only setting that have changed are the toolbar icons that I customised to my preferences.
- **[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640339/vs2010-always-relinks-the-project):** Everything is too complex for my skill level; I am used to some of the C/C++ syntax, but not as much with Visual Studio VC++.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default VS settings are not entirely compatible with your desired one-click-does-all usage.  C++ programmers normally favor building the program explicitly.  Use Build + Build or press the shortcut keys for that command.

You can change that.  Use Tools + Options, Projects and Solutions, Build and Run.  Note the "On Run, when projects are out of date" setting.  Change it to "Always build".  The one below that is best changed to "Do not launch".

Comment: Settings make sense, but what makes it "out of date?"

Comment: It is out of date when the source code is newer than the compiled program.  That includes never having compiled the program.