# VS2010: Project is out of date

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Every time I run the project VS2010 thinks the project is out of date. I went through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762930/vs2010-always-thinks-project-is-out-of-date-but-nothing-has-changed) and enabled debugging output via debugView. The concerning lines in debugView are the following:

```
00000001    0.00000000  [7792] devenv.exe Information: 0 :  
00000002    0.00001620  [7792] Project 'C:\code\MyProject\MyProject.vcxproj' not up to date because 'C:\PROGRAMDATA\SOPHOS\SOPHOS ANTI-VIRUS\CONFIG\CONFIG.BOPS' was modified at 09/24/2012 12:50:28, which is newer than 'C:\CODE\MyProject\DEBUG\MyProject.BSC' which was modified at 09/24/2012 16:07:24.
00000003    23.05826569 [7792] devenv.exe Information: 0 :  
00000004    23.05829620 [7792] Project 'C:\code\MyProject\MyProject.vcxproj' not up to date because 'C:\PROGRAMDATA\SOPHOS\SOPHOS ANTI-VIRUS\CONFIG\CONFIG.BOPS' was modified at 09/24/2012 12:50:28, which is newer than 'C:\CODE\MyProject\DEBUG\MyProject.BSC' which was modified at 09/24/2012 16:07:24.    
00000005    26.08067894 [7792] devenv.exe Information: 0 :  
00000006    26.08071709 [7792] Project 'C:\code\MyProject\MyProject.vcxproj' not up to date because 'C:\PROGRAMDATA\SOPHOS\SOPHOS ANTI-VIRUS\CONFIG\CONFIG.BOPS' was modified at 09/24/2012 12:50:28, which is newer than 'C:\CODE\MyProject\DEBUG\MyProject.BSC' which was modified at 09/24/2012 16:07:24.
```

First of all it is awful that VS2010 will look at some unrelated file (Well Microsoft!) but I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412023/vs2010-rebuilds-c-project-because-of-modified-irrelevant-files) solution and [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/649139/vs2010-does-complete-rebuild-based-on-completely-unrelated-file) both using `<ClNoDependencies>` to exclude the unrelated file but I have no luck.

I noticed that if I start out with a simple brand new project, it doesn't have this annoying `project is out of date` problem. This seems to be a know bug in VS2010 but it is mystery to me why VS2010 links my original project to that unrelated antivirus file but not the new project? Does this means there could be something I can fix in my original project to de-link the file? But I don't know what could it be since my project is not referencing that anti-virus file at all.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Do you have any files in the old project that are in the future? If not I would do a full clean.

Comment: I did full clean, didn't help.

Comment: The only time I've ever had this happen i had to run through the combination of making sure non-source-compiles (i.e. a .h file) that was deleted from disk was also deleted from the project. not your problem. Also, i had to turn OFF browser database building, delete all .BSC files in the build tree on disk, and after a restart of VS life was finally good again. I hope you can figure this out, because VS-build-all-the-time bugs just plain suck.

Comment: This has not happened to me in years and I am a C++ software developer who uses several versions of Visual Studio daily. I do not ever use .BSC files however.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known conflict between a bug in VS2010 and Sophos 10

http://community.sophos.com/t5/Sophos-EndUser-Protection/Buffer-overflow-prevention-system-and-msbuild/td-p/29483