# MS-Build: Displaying out-of-date dependencies

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I'm trying to debug an MS-Build in VS2010 setup that reports about a half-dozen projects are out-of-date on every build. I'm trying to trawl through the diagnostic output for a clue to what files are consider out-of-date and causing the rebuild.

Is there a simpler way to display the reason for dependencies to avoid looking for a needle in the proverbial haystack?

thanks
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question ["VS2010 always thinks project is out of date but nothing has changed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762930/vs2010-always-thinks-project-is-out-of-date-but-nothing-has-changed) shows you how to debug the dependencies checker of visual studio.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That's exactly what I was after.