# Project out of date in VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I tried searching for similar problems in here but all of them were too complex, I'm just starting out with C++ doing my Hello World, here's the code, just in case:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
return 0;
}
```

It only works fine if I compile it then start without debugging and without rebuilding it (when it says it's out of date).
If I start debugging it still says it's out of date but no matter if I rebuild it or not, the console shows up for like half a second then the program exits.
Why is this?

Comment: did you check http://stackoverflow.com/a/2853912/819272

Comment: Yes, thing is I don't have any header files, nothing else than my source file...

Comment: the program exits because it finished running. if you want to stop, you could add a breakpoint in the debugger at the `return 0;` line (which is not necessary anyway for correctness, because it's implicit)

Answer (score 1):

it is because your program executes then finishes through your

```
return 0;
```

so it happens and finishes almost instantly you need a way to be able to "pause" your applications execution to see your ouput. you could do std::cin >>. but i would recomend the use of system pause all you need to add is

```
System("pause");
```

and the

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

so your hello world applicaiton should look like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   std::cout << "hello world\n";
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

however

```
 system("pause")
```

is a windows specific feature and should be avoided for serious applications for various reasons.

Comment: Makes sense, however the only approach I said would work with me opens the window and doesn't exit but pauses waiting for the user to press any key to exit. So if it already does that do I really need to add something? Besides it's just one problem - it still says that the project is out of date for absolutely no reason. I don't know, really - total noob...

Comment: can you be more accurate about how its telling you the project is out of date? warnings when you compile?? if so paste the message from your output view. i personally havent fully transioned to vs2012 and still mostly use 2010. but i will still try to help.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to watch the output of a small program that finishes very quickly:

1. Put an infinite loop `while(true)`, or `for(;;)`,
2. Read from `std::cin`.
3. Put a **break point in your debugger** just before the exit from
   `main()`.
4. **Redirect your output** from the command line: `my_program.exe >
   my_output.txt`.

I prefer method no. 4 because it doesn't require changing your code.