# Unable to set path of msbuild.exe Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have recently started to use Visual Studio 2010. I have the following problem: My projects won't build. I get this error:

```
C:\...\visual studio 2010\Projects\String2\String2\String2.vcxproj : error MSB4014: The build stopped unexpectedly because of an internal failure.
C:\...\visual studio 2010\Projects\String2\String2\String2.vcxproj : error MSB4014: Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.BuildAbortedException: Build was canceled. MSBuild.exe could not be launched as a child node as it could not be found at the location "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe". If necessary, specify the correct location in the BuildParameters, or with the MSBUILD_EXE_PATH environment variable.
```

I checked the directory in question, and MSbuild.exe can indeed be found there. The path in the enviroment variable MSBUILD_EXE_PATH is set to the correct path. Still the project won't build. Sometimes I can change the environment variable to include "/msbuild.exe" at the end, and that will work. sometimes it won't. The problem returns every time I restart the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Activate diagnostics as written [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762930/vs2010-always-thinks-project-is-out-of-date-but-nothing-has-changed) and look what it reports. My experience is that sometimes the error that gets reported is pretty far from the real cause, like some file can't be created for being locked or directory missing yet it states some msbuild problem.  First line of defense is to delete the output and intermediate folders.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. The problem is that the compiler interferes with the anti-virus software (Avast). If I turn the anti-virus software of, the compiler works. This obviously presents a new problem - how do I keep the anti-virus on while using the compiler?