# visual studio 2010--projects out of date

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, opencv

I want to rebuild opencv sources on my own computer
so I follow this [tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#cpptutwindowsmakeown)

but at this step of building both of Debug and Release binaries , Visual studio ( Express) show a windows

saying that projects are out of date

what means that (I'm not familiar with this IDE) ? and how to fix it ?

NB:I didn't understand this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762930/vs2010-always-thinks-project-is-out-of-date-but-nothing-has-changed) on stackoverflow

I have edit the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\vcexpress.exe` configurantion file as it mentionned on the answer above but the problem is not soleved

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what you didn't understand about the other answer. It seems to be the answer to your question.

Comment: I have edit the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\vcexpress.exe configurantion file as it mentionned on the answer above but the problem is not soleved

Comment: So you didn't see any line in the build log that says 'file is missing'? Perhaps there is some other clue in the build log that tells you what is wrong.

Comment: After building the debug bianiries , I get an error the `ALL_BUILDS` file is missing and the debug folder is empty

Comment: Maybe this will give you an idea, http://answers.opencv.org/question/1635/unable-to-start-program-all_build/ ALL_BUILDS is not a file but a build target. For some reason your IDE thinks this is a file.