# "always rebuild" due to C++/CLI referencing COM in same solution

Tags: visual-studio, com, c++-cli, com-interop

I have a problem similar to [VS2010 always thinks project is out of date but nothing has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762930/vs2010-always-thinks-project-is-out-of-date-but-nothing-has-changed) (I'm also on VS 2010):

I [Enabled C++ project system logging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsproject/archive/2009/07/21/enable-c-project-system-logging.aspx) which told me that:

```
00000727    29.93245506 [5864] Project 'C:\foo.vcxproj' 
not up to date because 'C:\foo\INTEROP\INTEROP.bar.1.0.DLL' 
was modified at 01/22/2014 11:02:49, 
which is newer than 'C:\foo\RELEASE\METAGEN.WRITE.1.TLOG' 
which was modified at 01/22/2014 16:02:30.
```

This is apparently telling me that `foo` project must be rebuilt because either `bar.dll` or the interop have changed.

- `foo` is a C++/CLI project.
- `bar` is a COM DLL.
- `foo` has bar.dll as one of it's references.

  1. I haven't rebuilt `bar.dll` (date for the dll file is yesterday).
  2. I haven't modified any settings in project `foo` (to affect interop).

My question is: Why is Visual Studio deciding the interop is out of date and triggering a re-build on every single run of the application?

Note: This is a web application.  `foo` is directly referenced from the web.  `bar` is not directly referenced by the web.

**EDIT:**

I've created a simple look-alike solution with just 4 projects (2 for COM, website, and C++/CLI assembly).  It seems the C++/CLI assembly always updates the `INTEROP.bar.*.DLL` file every time any build is triggered.  This doesn't seem to be the case in the solution having problems.

This was my mis-understanding:  I thought the interop DLL should only be updated if 1) the reference is re-added.  2) The COM object being referenced (possibly just the API) changed.

Apparently, interop.dll is updated every build of caller.

Finally this wording is extremely confusing to me and seems incorrect:

> A was modified at 11:02:49, which is newer than B which was modified
>   at 16:02:30.

How could something from 11:02 be "newer than" something from 16:02?  (almost feels like a backwards `>=` / `<=` check)

PS - I'm not adding the example solution here, because it doesn't fail like the real solution does.

Comment: It rebuilds because the auto-generated interop assembly is clearly out of date.  You leave no guess whatsoever why re-generating it doesn't update the date on the interop.bar.1.0.dll file.  Try deleting it yourself.

Comment: The issue is not with the COM reference you added, it is with the interop assembly that was generated from the type library embedded inside the COM dll.  C:\foo\INTEROP\INTEROP.bar.1.0.DLL is that interop assembly.  It contains .NET compatible declarations of the methods implemented by the COM server.  It has the wrong date, that's why it keeps rebuilding.  I cannot guess why the date doesn't update when it gets re-generated, file system tunneling could be an explanation but your question doesn't give any leads.  Delete that file by hand and see what happens.

Comment: A timestamp that's 5 hours in the past does *not* give a strong hint that it is "updated too much".  I'm running out of ideas to get you to delete that file.

Comment: @HansPassant See the added answer if you like... I was trying to delete that file, but perhaps I wasn't doing it the right way or in the right order.  (The log statements from VC++ seem self-contradictory, but if no one ever hits this problem, and they shouldn't, we shouldn't have been doing this, then it's a moot point)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion.  It looks like I was leaving out one level of indirection in the dependencies.  The chain was: ASP.NET Website -> C++/CLI Assembly -> COM DLL -> C/C++ Native DLL.  All in a single solution.

We ended up refactoring to move all the COM DLL code into the C++/CLI Assembly changing it to merely: Web -> C++/CLI Assembly -> C/C++ Native DLL.  At this point the problem went away.

It's not a very satisfying answer, but I don't have enough spare cycles to really dig into it now that it's no longer causing trouble.