# Debugging Visual Studio build dependencies - avoiding unnecessary project builds

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2015

Using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise on Windows 10 64-bit.  Working with a solution which contains a bunch of C# library projects.

When building the solution, then building it again, then repeating this, each time there are a handful of projects which build every time.  There have been no changes to any of the source files, yet VS still wants to build these projects.

Anyone have any tips on debugging the build dependencies to figure out WHY it wants to build these projects each time?

Comment: Well, I think this is more likely to apply only to c++, but there's this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762930/vs2010-always-thinks-project-is-out-of-date-but-nothing-has-changed
I would begin by looking at post-build events and msbuild customizations which are breaking the dependency tracking. Perhaps some code generation is running every time and producing an identical (but newly-timestamped) file.