# Always telling me my project is out of date

Tags: visual-studio

I have just built my project and then if I click F5 it always wants to build it again. Why?

How can I fix that?

[image: Build]

Comment: this is always my question!

Comment: Think I might have found a related question. Building with verbose diagnostics. I removed some redundant image references from my vxproj file. Will update you.

Comment: This helped me resolve the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14769391/2287576

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS2010 always thinks project is out of date but nothing has changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762930/vs2010-always-thinks-project-is-out-of-date-but-nothing-has-changed)

Comment: A possible reason is that you reference a missing file in your project.