# Entire solution is always rebuild (Visual Studio 2015 using IncrediBuild 7.31)

Tags: visual-studio, build, incredibuild

When compiling a particular solution in Visual Studio 2015 using IncrediBuild 7.31 it always insist on rebuilding the entire solution even when no files have changed. I only see this behaviour for the solution on a particular (older) branch.

I have used the setting from the answer to [VS2010 always thinks project is out of date but nothing has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762930/vs2010-always-thinks-project-is-out-of-date-but-nothing-has-changed/14769391#14769391): "Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run->MSBuild project build output verbosity": Diagnostic. This gives me output like this:

```
1>Project not up to date because the following 36 build inputs were missing:
1> up to date is missing: 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\XOREAX\INCREDIBUILD\MODULECACHE\220C7\11AC8\C1.DLL'
1> up to date is missing: 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\XOREAX\INCREDIBUILD\MODULECACHE\220C7\11AC8\C1XX.DLL'
1> up to date is missing: 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\XOREAX\INCREDIBUILD\MODULECACHE\220C7\11AC8\C2.DLL'
1> up to date is missing: 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\XOREAX\INCREDIBUILD\MODULECACHE\2B0E5\11AC8\C1.DLL'
```

Does anyone know how I can avoid that the compiler thinks that "Project not up to date"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the /Bv flag solves the problem for me. (It turns out that a colleague of mine had fixed it in the newer branch.)

I consider it a bug in IncrediBuild.

Comment: Hi nielses, my name is Dori and I'm from the IncrediBuild team. This is the first time we hear about this issue and will appreciate if you could approach our support at support@incredibuild.com to receive instructions on how to send us an extended log so we can address the problem you report in a proper manner. Disclaimer - the writer works at IncrediBuild

Comment: Thank you, but actually my colleague explains that "he sent our diagnostic build log files to Xoreax, and they told him to remove /Bv". So thanks to IncrediBuild support for resolving this. You might have our specifc case in your records.